# Crystal report or flow document in WPF

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

I have wpf application and it needs report printing. for example daily, monthly sales. Should I use Crystal report or Flow Document with tabular will do? I know this is naive question.

I need faster and free reporting solution....

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services are well worth looking in to: in my experience far less buggy than Crystal and all you need to is add a Report (RDL) file to your project and drag on a viewer (with WPF may be necessary to host it in a WindowsFormsHost control, though).  Or you can go the whole hog and install SQL Server with reporting services, so that the reports are processed on the server.  You get a load of decent export options (PDF, HTML,..) and there's plenty of flexibility and customisation for logic and rules in the report.